# css flex box challenge -3

Tags: html, css

**please do help in making this CSS page I posted below **
take it as a challenge , I tried but  failed in it.
have a nice day[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqQWc.jpg)

Comment: Share at least what you tried, to show some type of effort.

Comment: This looks like a grid, have you tried that? Give it a go then if you are still stuck put your code into your question and describe what isn’t working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could've made your question better by at least showing your code attempt(s), so someone can help you with the exact thing you are stuck at.

I **did** think this challenge might be interesting to have a go at so here's my attempt (also at my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/akcumeh/pen/NWXpydq)):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width: 1360px;
    height: 760px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

nav {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 20%;
    height: 104.5%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: grey;
}

div {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: inherit;
    height: 25%;

    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: indianred;
}

article {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: inherit;
    height: 50%;

    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: sandybrown;
}

footer {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;

    width: inherit;
    height: 25%;

    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <nav>
            Nav!
        </nav>
        <div>
            <header>
                Header!
            </header>
            <article>
                Article!
            </article>
            <footer>
                Footer!
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i have a question why we use coloumn in flex direction .... why not row

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  Take a look at this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:'flex'">
   <nav> </nav>
   <div style="display: 'flex'; flex-direction:'column' "> 
    <header> </header>
    <div> </div>
    <footer> </footer>
  </div>
 </div>
```